# How do I connect my raspberry pi to its own network?

Tags: networking, dhcp, internet, dns, hostapd

I use `hostapd` to create a wireless AP and I use `dnsmasq` to hand out ip addresses. In order for `dnsmasq` to work I have turned off the my dhcp client deamon `dhcpcd`. I do not want my network to be connected to any other network such as the internet so I have not bridged any of my interfaces.

I have `sshd` and some other programs that opens a port to the network. The **issue** is that those programs, along with `sshd`, cannot be accessed from clients on the network. The clients that gets connected to my raspberry pies AP gets an IP address successfully from `dnsmasq` but the raspberry pi itself doesn't seem to be connected to the network it is hosting. (as seen by `ip r`, `ip a` and `ping` command)

What I have tried is to ping various clients on the network. From the clients pov, when pinging or mapping the network, the hosting raspberry pi cannot be found. From the hosting raspberry pies pov, when pinging the client on it's given IP address, I get the response that the network is not accessible.

Here are some outputs to help you help me. Start the AP:

```
wpa_cli terminate;
systemctl stop dhcpcd;
systemctl start hostapd;
systemctl start dnsmasq;
```

From the hosting rpi pov:

```
$ ping 192.168.10.10 # same for x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.0
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

$ ip route
# No output / empty routing table <- this could be a part of the issue

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:42:db:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:17:8e:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The output from the `ip addr` above is not fixed, sometimes it's empty, what I guess is that it is stuck from before I stopped `dhcpcd` and disconnected from my internet router.

From client pov:

```
$ ping 192.168.10.1 ## same output for x.x.x.0 too
ping 192.168.10.1
PING 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.10.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5054ms
pipe 3

$ ping 192.168.10.10 ## pinging the client itself
ping 192.168.10.10
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
^C
--- 192.168.10.10 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3039ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.031/0.058/0.122/0.036 ms

$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 302 
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.10 

$ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:61:9d:1b:3f:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

To summarize: **How can I get the hosting raspberry pi on the network?** ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody encounters this in the future, running following commands after starting the AP and dhcp server did the job:

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1
```

This is because I needed to setup an IP address for the wlan0 interface, and then route it to the network. That way the rpi is connected to the network since all of the network requests gets routed to the right address.

Comment: Note `ifconfig` and `route` are obsolete according to their own `man` pages, superseded by `ip a[ddr]`/`ip l[ink]` and `ip r[oute]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done will NOT disable dhcpcd or enable dnsmasq. You would have to repeat EVERY time you reboot.

There is no need to disable dhcpcd; indeed it is normal to use it to assign an IP address.

Your Pi is unreachable because it doesn't have an IP

Comment: I see that I used the wrong wording, my intention is to be able to switch between AP and being connected to the internet. dhcpcd interrupted the dnsmasq somehow so my clients didn't get an IP address.

Comment: However, assigning my PI an IP did the trick.

Comment: What you have done is a kluge. You should setup properly using the Raspberry Pi Ltd. Instructions.